# trouble setting boundaries in a game in isometric view?

Tags: python, math, isometric

I'm trying to write a game in isometric view, but I'm not sure how to set proper boundaries to stop the player from leaving the board. The board is shaped like a chessboard.

```
if keys[K_LEFT] and guyX > 50: #guyX is the player's x cord
        guyX -= 10
if keys[K_RIGHT] and guyX < 1010:
        guyX += 10
if keys[K_DOWN] and guyY < 680: #guyY is the player's y cord
        guyY += 10
if keys[K_UP] and guyY > 200:
        guyY -= 10
```

My chessboard goes from 50,440 to 530,200 to 1010,440 then to 530,680 
I want to stop my player from leaving the chessboard, what other limits can i put on my code that will stop the player from doing so?

Comment: Should the player's position not better be in *game board* coordinates? Then it's a simple test against the game board edges.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by game board cords... do you mean mx,my?

Comment: @KarinaMeowmeow I think Jongware is suggesting that you convert the screen coordinates (which I'm guessing is what you're giving us) into coordinates on the board, and then you can do the bounds check there. (Which will be easier, since it's a square.)

Answer (score 1):

As Jongware says it will be much easier to work on game board coordinates and have a transformation from those to screen coordinated.

It your game board is from 0 to 8 in the x direction and from 0 to 8 in the y direction your will want a transformation like

```
screen_x = screen_x0 + u_x * game_x + v_x * game_y
screen_y = screen_y0 + u_y * game_x + v_y * game_y
```

In your case

```
screen_x0 = 50
screen_y0 = 440
u_x = (530 - 50) / 8
u_y = (200 - 200) / 8
v_x = (1010 - 530) / 8
v_y = (440 - 200) / 8
```

To get back game coordinated

```
det = u_x * v_y - u_y * v_x
x1 = screen_x - screen_x0
y1 = screen_y - screen_y0
game_x = 8 / det * (  v_y * x1 - v_x * y1 )
game_y = 8 / det * ( -u_y * x1 + u_x * y1 )
```

Then you can simply test game_x >= 0, game_x <8, game_y >= 0, game_y <8 to find if the position is on the board.

See [Isometric graphics in video games and pixel art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_graphics_in_video_games_and_pixel_art) for a more efficient method.